# How to manage duplicated Data between different tables in Query-Driven Data Model in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, duplicates, datamodel

I'm new in Cassandra NOSQL DB. I've read [A Big Data Modeling Methodology for Apache Cassandra](http://www.cs.wayne.edu/andrey/papers/TR-BIGDATA-05-2015-CKL.pdf) and [Basic Rules of Cassandra Data Modeling](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/basic-rules-of-cassandra-data-modeling) as useful articles about data modelling in Cassandra. In this pages, it's mentioned that, data duplication is used to achieve best performance (more write) based on Query-Driven methodology.OK! We will have a physical diagram as this:
[image]
As you see, ave-rating is duplicated in three tables.The question is that, when we want to update or insert ave-rating:

- Does Cassandra have any tools itself to manage write in any tables having this column?(CRUD operations in duplicated Data toward some columns)
- Is there any third-party tool for issue, above?
- Should this issue be handled in application level? if yes, what is the best practice, then?

Answer (score 3):

> Does Cassandra have any tools itself to manage write in any tables having this column?

Yes, look at materialized views: http://www.doanduyhai.com/blog/?p=1930
And here too: http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/understanding-materialized-views

Comment: Thank you, your article was useful.I edited the picture, above.(now,it is complete) So, if I understand correctly, I can use artifacts-by-auther table as base table and change the artifacts and artifacts-by-venue table to materialized views. But what should I do for artifact-by-user,for example. it has artifact-title column as artifact-by-auther table. when this column changes in  artifact-by-auther, how the change will apply in artifact-by-user? should I use batch-log, or there is a better way?

Comment: For `artifact-by-user`, you can create it as a view of `artifact-by-author` with `PRIMARY KEY((user_id), year, artifact_id, author)`. If the `artifact-title` column is updated in the base table `artifact-by-author`, the view `artifiact-by-user` will be updated automatically by Cassandra. Another WARNING, you need to include the collections `authors` (list<text>) and `keywords` (set<text>) in **all the views**, see this JIRA: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-11069

Comment: As I mentioned in question, I try  to use query-driven methodology. The artifact-by-user table will answer Q7 which will find artifacts published after a certain year that a given user liked, order results by DESC year. So, the relation between users and artifacts is n-n. If I use user-id in   artifact-by-author the answer of Q2 (witch finds artifacts published by a given auther order results by year-desc) will repeat n times, n is the count of users who like that artifact; and it seems pointless. what's your opinion?

Comment: It seems that, selecting artifact-by-author as base table, for artifacts and artifacts-by-venue has the same problem, too. Imagine, we had an artifact with 3 authors. When we want to find an artifact's information based on artifact-id (Q9) it will return 3 lines as result (per result for each auther)

Comment: You're right when you're mentioning the **n-n** relationships. There is no other way around, and Cassandra clustering columns have been designed for such **n-n** scenarios. There is a possible optimization to avoid **repeating** the same normal columns for each different clustering column: define them as **static columns**. But with static columns you can not include them in materialized views ....

Comment: So, what can help us in this case? what's your opinion about bach-log (mentioned in second link in question)?

Comment: If we have to apply changes to tables with alike columns with hand, is there any tools to handle this?

Comment: Batch log is a viable option. Indeed, before **materialized views** were introduced in **Cassandra 3.0**, most people deal with denormalization using logged batch. But it will put the burden on the client application code to synchronize between different tables.